# mysql create trigger on insert do update using where condition is not working

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

i have a table orderlines on insert trigger is working but in ordernumber table i want to update ordernumber based on serialnumber

so for updates i have written two lines

line 1: `UPDATE TEMPSTORAGE SET`ORDERNUMBER`=orderno+1,`SERIALNUMBER`=serialno;`
        is working fine without where condition

line 2: `UPDATE ORDERNUMBER SET`ORDERNUMBER`=orderno+1 WHERE`SERIALNUMBER`= serialno;`
        is not working can any body suggest me.... how to update ordernumber based on 
        serial number

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `temp`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trg_updateordernumber`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_updateordernumber` AFTER INSERT ON `ORDERLINES` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        DECLARE orderno VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE serialno VARCHAR(255);
        SET @orderno = 'xxx';

        SELECT ORDERNUMBER, SERIALNUMBER INTO orderno, serialno 
        FROM ORDERLINES 
        WHERE ID=NEW.ID;

        UPDATE TEMPSTORAGE SET 
            `ORDERNUMBER` =orderno+1, 
            `SERIALNUMBER` =serialno;

        UPDATE ORDERNUMBER SET 
            `ORDERNUMBER`=orderno+1 
        WHERE `SERIALNUMBER` = serialno;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

is there any problem with mysql triggers (hope not)....?
if not then plz suggest me why line2 is not working ?

Thanks and regards;

Comment: line 2 is *Not working* means what? You got any error? And, btw, do you know what is the return type of a varchar plus a number?

Comment: i didnt get any error. but it seems line2 is not executing but line1 is working fine and result is getting temperory table (which i created for debugging) and for the timebeing i am not worrying about datatypes.

Comment: can we use where clause inside triggers generally ... ?

Comment: Where clause in triggers is absolutely acceptable.

Comment: then why my line2 is not working.... ?

Comment: I repeat. *Not working means what?* 1. what do you have. 2. what is your expected output? 3. what is current output. 4. Any error produced?

Comment: Do the tables `ORDERLINES` and `ORDERNUMBER` have any PK-FK relation?

Comment: tables doesnt have a fk relation, ill add fk and ill check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger but not `AFTER INSERT`.

I am not sure what the relation between `ORDERLINES` and `ORDERNUMBER` tables,
but suggest to try the following ( not tested ):

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `temp`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trg_updateordernumber`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_updateordernumber` BEFORE INSERT ON `ORDERLINES` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE TEMPSTORAGE SET 
            `ORDERNUMBER` =NEW.ORDERNUMBER+1, 
            `SERIALNUMBER` =NEW.SERIALNUMBER;

        UPDATE ORDERNUMBER SET 
            `ORDERNUMBER`==NEW.ORDERNUMBER+1 
        WHERE `SERIALNUMBER` = NEW.SERIALNUMBER;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```